# Finding a graph that satisfies all minimal dominating sets avoiding a vertex.

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph $G = (V , E)$, a subset $D ⊆ V$ is a *dominating set* if
> each vertex is either in $D$ or has at least one neighbor in $D$. The
> set $D$ is *minimal* if no proper subset $D' ⊂ D$ is a dominating set.

**My question is:**  For any graph $G$, does the union of all minimal dominating sets of $G$ equal the vertex set of $G$? If not, I am searching for a graph that satisfies the property of all minimal dominating sets avoiding a specific vertex.

---

I feel that starting from any vertex can induce a minimal dominating set (I haven't figured out the proof yet). (If we change "minimal dominating set" to "minimum dominating set", it doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: If $D$ is a minimal dominating set for the subgraph of $G$ induced by $\{x\in V(G):d(x,v)\gt1\}$ then won't $D\cup\{v\}$ be a minimal dominating set for $G$?

Comment: @bof You have inspired me. We can choose a minimal dominating set $D_1$ in $G-(v\cup N_G(v))$ where $N_G(v)$ is the set of all the neighbors of $v$, and then $D_1\cup\{v\} $ is a minimal dominating set of $G$. (We can prove this  property from the difinition of minimal dominating sets.) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, every independent set is contained in a maximal independent set. (This is even true for infinite graphs, assuming the axiom of choice.) Since every maximal independent set is a minimal dominating set, and since a set consisting of a single vertex is independent, this statement is stronger and more general than the one you wanted to prove.